# JavaScript/TypeScript Array interface[] , group by type to send 1 of many functions

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, prototype, solid-principles

I have an `array` of Question (`interface`) that I need to send to 1 of many functions based on Question type. I think my series of `if` statements is very ugly and am hoping there is a way of doing this that adheres to SOLID. I believe I am violating O (Open for extension, closed for modification).

```
renderQuestionList(contents: Question[]): HTMLElement {
    return yo`
        <div>${contents.map(q => {
            if (q.type == 'passfailna') { return this.renderQuestionPassfailna(q) };
            if (q.type == 'yesno') { return this.renderQuestionYesno(q) };
            if (q.type == 'numeric') { return this.renderQustionNumeric(q) };
        })}
        </div>`;
}
```

Then,

```
    renderQuestionPassfailna(q: Question): any {
        return yo`<div>Stuff</div>`;
    }
    renderQuestionYesno(q: Question): any {
         return yo`<div>Other Stuff</div>`;
    }
    renderQustionNumeric(q: Question): any {
         return yo`<div>I'm Helping!</div>`;
    }
```

Comment: Ever considered using a template engine? I've personally made this: https://github.com/JO3-W3B-D3V/Ninja

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the logic inside the template is too large, then it can be moved to a function, such as

```
renderQuestionList(contents: Question[]): HTMLElement {
    return yo`
        <div>${contents.map(q => renderQuestion(q))}
        </div>`;
}

    renderQuestion(q):HTMLElement {
        if (q.type == 'passfailna') { return this.renderQuestionPassfailna(q) };
        if (q.type == 'yesno') { return this.renderQuestionYesno(q) };
        if (q.type == 'numeric') { return this.renderQustionNumeric(q) };
    }
```

However, I would question the wisdom of generating such a large tree all at once.  When I use YO I prefer to generate small items, and insert them using `appendChild`.  For example,

```
renderQuestionList(contents: Question[]): HTMLElement {
    let div = yo`<div> </div>`;
    contents.forEach(q => {
         div.appendChild(renderQuestion(q));
    });
    return div;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

it is ugly. How about building a map of functions? Perhaps something like

```
constructor() {
   this.questions = {
      passfailna: q => this.renderQuestionPassfailna(q),
      yesno: q => this.renderQuestionYesno(q),
      numeric: q => return this.renderQustionNumeric(q)
   };
}

renderQuestionList(contents: Question[]): HTMLElement {
    return yo`<div>${contents.map(q => this.questions[q.type](q))}</div>`;
}
```

Comment: Someone (irl) pointed out to me that I should be careful with my use of yoyo.js. It apparently cannot handle callbacks in the way it should, or in a way I would expect. Thank you!